# Get df subset based on condition applied to the list item

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I would like to loop over the group of items and use that to check condition for subsetting dataframe. My code throws error right now. I want to check if each item in en_nam1 passes en1$attributes == item. If it passes the condition then I want to select the row and add in another dataframe to return. Thank you.

```
A tibble: 3 x 2
  attributes models   
  <chr>      <list>   
1 AT01S      <chr [2]>
2 AT02S      <chr [2]>
3 AGG101     <chr [1]>
4 AGG102     <chr [1]>
5 AGG103     <chr [1]>
6 AGG104     <chr [1]>

en_nam1
[1] "AT01S"  "AT02S"  "AGG101"

My code:
 en_nam1 %>%
+ map(~subset(en1, en1$attributes == .x))

Expected result:
 A tibble: 3 x 2
  attributes models   
  <chr>      <list>   
1 AT01S      <chr [2]>
2 AT02S      <chr [2]>
3 AGG101     <chr [1]>
```

Comment: What is the issue with the code

Comment: You could do this more easily with `en1 %>% filter(attributes %in% en_nam1)` or `subset(en1, attributes %in% en_nam1)`

Comment: @akrun Ahhh!!! perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @akrun I was gettin error. Error: Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.

Comment: If the `en_nam1` is the vector object name and `en1` is the dataset, it is not clear whyyou get an error

Comment: can you show dput of first few rows

Comment: @akrun structure(list(attributes = c("AT01S", "AT02S", "AGG101"), models = list(
    c("EADS14", "EADS142"), c("EADS14", "EADS142"), "EADS03")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Based on the structure showed, it is working for me though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need a loop here.  It is more direct with `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
en1 %>%
  filter(attributes %in% en_nam1)
```

or `subset` in `base R`

```
subset(en1, attributes %in% en_nam1)
```